# PHP preg_split to match every line except empty lines

Tags: php, regex

How to exclude empty lines in `pref_split`.

example: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/qRm#tab-preg-split

Comment: Can `\r` appear multiple time in the middle of the text, otherwise `trim()` the text before split it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) flag:

```
$string = "Name|name
Last|f_name
";
print_r(preg_split('/\R/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => Name|name
    [1] => Last|f_name 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/8Or5C)